# Initialization error when calling static method in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class with static method for encryption and decryption. I am writing test for these methods but I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException with not initialized message.

```
public final class CipherUtil {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CipherUtil.class);

private static final String SECRET_KEY = "XXX";
private static Cipher cipher;
private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;

static{
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
    }
    byte[] key = null;
    try {
        key = Hex.decodeHex(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray());
    } catch (DecoderException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
    }
    secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
}

private CipherUtil() { }

public static String encrypt(String plainText) { 
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
  ... 
}
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) { 
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
  ...
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@Test
public void testEncryptDecrypt() {
    String plainText = "Secret Message";
    String encryptedText = CipherUtil.encrypt(plainText);
    assertThat(encryptedText, not(equalTo(plainText)));
    String decryptedText = CipherUtil.decrypt(encryptedText);
    assertThat(decryptedText, is(equalTo(plainText)));
    assertThat(encryptedText, not(equalTo(decryptedText)));
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized
```

Comment: Don't do this with statics, and don't make the class final. It'll make it impossible to mock out this object when unit-testing classes that collaborate with it.

Comment: The problem is not the statics, you just need to call init on your cipher: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Comment: @ Renato I do have init call.See updated question code

Comment: @Engineer Dollery I am making static so that not initilZATION HASN'T TO BE DONE everytime.

Comment: According to the error message, you have not initialized it...  maybe you forgot to do it somewhere? Why don't you call init right after you get an instance of it? BTW, You can use the singleton pattern to achieve the same result (init it only once) without having to make all your methods static.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're shouting by accident... Why don't you want to initialize this more than once? Do you have a performance problem that you have verified in an optimizer that proves that this is a problem? Anyway, basically you're using `static` as a substitute for a singleton, and that is an ineffective solution in a lot of environments (most environments), because of classloader issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you can't initialize the object twice. You would need one static instance for decrypt mode, one for encrypt mode, and one for any other mode you want to use. You would need to move the init call from the method to the static constructor(although I agree with Engineer Dollery that this shouldn't be a static).